# Save next word, if a given word is found (C++)

Tags: c++, file

I'm pretty new to C++. I have a text doc that looks like this:

InputFile.txt

```
...
.
..
.
.
....
 TIME/DISTANCE =      500/ 0.1500E+05
..
..
.
 ...
 TIME/DISTANCE =      500/ 1.5400E+02
.
...
...
.
 TIME/DISTANCE =      500/ 320.0565
..
..
.
.
...
```

The one line shown keeps repeating throughout the file. My objective is to save all the numbers after the `500/` into an array/vector/another file/anything. I know how to read a file and get a line:

```
string line;
vector <string> v1;
ifstream txtfile ("InputFile.txt");
if (txtfile.is_open())
{
    while (txtfile.good())
    {
        while( getline( txtfile, line ) )
        {
            // ?????
            // if(line.find("500/") != string::npos)
            // ?????
        }
    }
    txtfile.close();
}
```

Does anybody have a solution? Or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Both proposed solutions (Jerry's and Galik's) work perfectly. I love this community. :)

Comment: The `while (txtfile.good())` loop is redundant as is the `if (txtfile.is_open())` unless you use it to report that the file failed to open or something.

Comment: @Galik - Yeah the piece of code after this prints an error message if the file is not found or something.

Comment: See basic_string methods at cppreference.com. Use find to locate start of 500/. If not npos, add 4 and get s=substr(found+4). Now you can use istringstream(s) >> doubleval to converti it to double, if needed. vector<double> x.push_back(doubleval). If you want to learn, learn by reading tutorials. This is pretty basic.

Comment: @Pihhan - I got till the point where I have the position of 500/. The next part confused me. I'm going to ask you the same embarrassing question that I asked Galik. Why the number 4 in 'found + 4' ? Does it have to do with memory storage of a string or something?

Comment: Because strlen("500/") == 4. Because you want end of that string and find() returns start of it. You could have use string offset("500/); ... string rest = line.substr(line.find(offset)+offset.size()) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those rare cases that (IMO) it may make sense to use `sscanf` in C++.

```
std::string line;
std::vector<double> numbers;

while (std::getline(txtfile, line)) {
    double d;
    if (1==sscanf(line.c_str(), " TIME/DISTANCE = 500 / %lf", &d))
        numbers.push_back(d);
}
```

This takes each line, and attempts to treat it as having the format you care about. Where that succeeded, the return value from `sscanf` will be 1 (the number of items converted). Where it fails, the return value will be 0 (i.e., it didn't convert anything successfully). Then we save it if (and only if) there was a successful conversion.

Also note that `sscanf` is "smart" enough to treat a single space in the format string as matching an arbitrary amount of white-space in the input, so we don't have to try to match the amount of white space precisely.

We could vary this somewhat. If there has to be a number before the '/', but it *could* be something different from `500`, we could replace that part of the format string with `%*d`. That means `sscanf` will search for a number (specifically an integer) there, but not assign it to anything. If it finds something other than an integer, conversion will fail, so (for example) `TIME/DISTANCE ABC/1.234` would fail, but `TIME/DISTANCE 234/1.l234` would succeed.

Comment: I will try this out and report back. Thank you. I was not aware that such functionality existed.

Comment: Its not working for some reason. I did exactly as you suggested and I'm getting gibberish as saved output. Any ideas?

`-9.25596e+061`    
`-9.25596e+061`
`-9.25596e+061`

Comment: @user3845866: Oops. I just demonstrated not just one, but two of the shortcomings of `scanf`. One is that it isn't type-safe (and I had a mismatch between the passed type and what the format string told it to expect). The other is that although `scanf` formats are *mostly* the same as `printf` formats, they differ in a *few* cases: `%f` is the format for a `double` with `printf`, but the format for a `float` with `scanf`. You need to use `%lf` to read a `double`. My apologies.

Comment: Haha I didn't notice that either. Made the change and it works perfectly. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

When processing your line then you can use `line.find()` to check its the right line and to find your data:

```
if(line.find("TIME/DISTANCE") != std::string::npos)
{
    // this is the correct line
}
```

Once you have the correct line you can get the position of the data like this:

```
std::string::size_type pos = line.find("500/");

if(pos != std::string::npos)
{
    // pos holds the position of the numbers you want

    std::string wanted_numbers = lint.substr(pos + 4); // get only the numbers in a string
}
```

Hope that helps

**EDIT:** Fixed bug (adding 4 to pos to skip over the "500/" part)

Comment: I will try this and report back.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much. I have just one noob question that I'm very embarrassed to ask but I will anyway because I have to learn. Why the number 4 in `pos + 4` ? Does it have to do with memory storage of a string or something?

Comment: I marked the other answer as Accepted only because it gives me the numbers as doubles which saves me a step of converting them. Nonetheless, I really do appreciate your response. This was closer to my line of thinking as well.

Comment: @user3845866: the "+4" is because `500/` is 4 characters, so it needs to start looking for number you care about after that. This also means it's fairly fragile-for example, `500 /` (note the added space) will break it--for that case, you'd need `+5`, because the part that needs to be skipped is now 5 characters long.

Comment: `line.find("500/");` gives you the position of the **beginning** of the "500/" string but you need the position of the **end** where the numbers you want are.

Comment: @Galik Oh my God. Now I feel stupid. I should have figured that out. Thank you once again.